# Using JS getting data from php array

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

I want to get data on click from an array echoed in span, but js code is fetching desired data from first span only, for remaining spans too.(using codeigniter)
,here's the html code

```
<div class="row sideBar">
          <?php foreach($data1 as $key1): ?>
          <div class="row sideBar-body">

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9 sideBar-main">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 sideBar-name">
                <a class="rrid"> <span class="name-meta" id="rname" ><?= $key1['name'] ?>
                </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pull-right sideBar-time">
                  <span class="time-meta pull-right" id="rid" ><?= $key1['id'] ?>
                </span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
```

and here's the JS code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".rrid").click(function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var rid= document.getElementById("rid").innerText;
                        var rname= document.getElementById("rname").innerText;

                        console.log(rid);
                        if(rid==''){
                          alert('ok');
                      }
                      else{

                        $("#conversation").load("chat/rmessage",{
                            rid : rid,
                            rname: rname
                        });
                      }
```

Comment: You can't have more than one element with same id, instead use class `$('.name-meta').click(function(){var rid = $(this).text();})`

Comment: On adding class to it, its picking same id for other span.

Comment: `<a id="rrid"> <span class="name-meta" id="rname" data-rname="<?= $key1['name'] ?>" data-rid="<?= $key1['rid'] ?>"><?= $key1['name'] ?></a>                          $('.name-meta').click(function(){var rname = $(this).data('rname'); var rid = $(this).data('rid');})`

Comment: i have edited it, but on replacing class, its returning value of first span only.

Comment: If you have more than one element with same id, it will get the first one